# How to compare a string char and an char int in c++?

Tags: c++

```
string str='中test'

first_char = str[0]
```

How can I compare first_char with an int 128? I want to test whether the first char is an ascii or not.

Something like this:

```
if char(first_char) < 128:
   return true
```

Comment: `''` is for a single character. Do this: `string str="中test"; auto first_char = str[0]; if( static_cast<int>(first_char) < 128) { Your code...}`

Comment: @Asesh no need for the static_cast. All types narrower than int will be promoted to int before any operations

Comment: Another option is to `#include <cctype>` and test `if (isascii(static_cast<unsigned char>(first_char))) return true;` (the cast to `unsigned char` is necessary to satisfy the `ccytpe` requirement the argument `"must have the value of an unsigned char..."` -- though if it is contained in `std::string` you should be fine)

Comment: So it goes like this: auto first_char = str[0]; if( int(first_char) < 128) { Your code...} @Asesh

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  What's `isascii` MSVC extension?

Comment: `isascii` is a POSIX function found in `<ctype.h>`. You’ll find it on Linux boxes.

Comment: Since a char is signed, the range is -128...+127. checking with <128 may always return true, I have used in my utf8 class isAscii = ((value & 0x80) ==0);
For details: https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

In C++ (and C), the *signedness* of a `char` is **implementation-defined**. Hence, a simple less-than operator will not suffice. You need some bitwise action:

```
bool is_ascii( char c )
{
  return !(c & 0x80);
}
```

As soon as you begin messing with UTF-8 text (or any other non-ASCII text) the usual assumptions about what a *character* is go out the window. You should use a library, such as [ICU](https://icu.unicode.org), to help you. (Every modern OS has ICU installed already, so this should not be a difficult requirement.)